# Parent/Child Relationships failing when getting data from parent class, with multiple forms open

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a main form, and some sub forms, and each sub form can have some sub forms. When I have multiple sub forms open, and I try to get data from the parent form, it returns the data from the wrong parent form.

For example I have two instances of Mainform.subform running. If I do something like this in a child form of one instance of the subform. It returns data from the other subform.

```
 dim l = Mainform.subform.listofdata
```

**Edit**
I am using visual Studio 2008. Winforms, form designed using designer.

In my mainform I am doing this

```
 Protected Friend frmMain as Mainform
 frmmain = new mainform
```

In frmMain I am doing this

```
Protected Friend  frmsub as new Subform'
frmsub = new subform
```

In the SubSubForm I am doing this

```
 For each item in frmmain.frmsub.listofdata
 \\Do Something
next
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? is this WinForms or ASP.NET? Also, did you use Visual Studio to design the forms? How are you instantiating the child forms (subforms)? If you are instantiating them with names, you could use that name as a reference into the "Controls" property of the Mainform object. thx!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider setting the [Parent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent(VS.71).aspx) property of the child forms, and then use the parent/child relationship to find the correct listofdata that you're looking for. Something like `Me.Parent.listofdata`. Hopefully this is an option in your particular case - good luck!